# Agent Chat : Chat pop-up window if user is idle for xx seconds on the page

Tags: visualforce, community, salesforce1-app, liveagent, livechattranscript

In the agent chat(live chat) in salesforce can we show the notification popup when the user is ideal for xx seconds on the community page. Like salesforce live chat window popup show on the login page

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There's a declarative way of doing this for agents shown in [documentation.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=live_agent_deployment_settings.htm&type=5)

You can also make a VF component to do the same action I think for chat visitors.

> Idle Connection Warning Duration  Indicates the duration, in seconds,
>   that the customer can remain idle or disconnected before a warning is
>   sent to the agent. The default value is 40 seconds. Appears when
>   Enable Custom Timeouts is selected.